# printing pages from m.s.e.

Tags: discussion, export

I went to a question on this m.s.e. and printed it, expecting to see the page as it had appeared in the browser window.   But the mathematical notation appears in the printed copy as unrendered TeX code.  Is this normal?  Can something be done about it?

Comment: What browser and operating system? Does it look OK in the "print preview" option (if you have one)?

Comment: I guess you know that there exists [StackPrinter](http://www.stackprinter.com/), see e.g. [this question](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3079/is-it-possible-to-convert-and-possibly-download-the-answers-discussions-in-pdf). It gives, in my opinion, somewhat better results then printing out directly the question from the browser. (Of course, this is only tangential to your question, it does not answer why TeX-code was not rendered.)

Answer (score 5):

Printing an answer by id is now supported on [StackPrinter](http://www.stackprinter.com/).

To print all:
http://www.stackprinter.com/export?question=6593&service=math.meta.stackexchange

To print a specific answer:
http://www.stackprinter.com/export?question=6593&service=math.meta.stackexchange&answer=6596

To print a specific answer keeping the question:
http://www.stackprinter.com/export?question=6593&service=math.meta.stackexchange&answer=6596&hidequestion=false

Have a look to the [Api doc](http://www.stackprinter.com/docs/api.txt).

Answer (score 3):

I printed it as a pdf and all the math is typeset neatly. I did not try printing directly to a printer since I do not have access to one now. You could try to print it as a pdf and then try to print it using a printer. I am on Chrome Version $23.0.1271.64$ on Mac OS X $10.7.5$.

[This is the question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/21330/closed-form-for-sum-frac1nn) I printed and [here is the printed pdf](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/5805435/Mathematics.pdf).

Comment: I don't see any option labeled "print as pdf" available to me on the machine on which I did this, but "print to a file" is available, and then it saves it as a pdf file.  It does look OK when I do that, but I haven't yet tried printing the pdf file since I'm not physically located where I have access to the printer.  Further information might follow when I can do that.....

Comment: @MichaelHardy If the pdf file looks fine, you should get the same while you print it on paper using a printer as well. So I guess it should be fine.

Answer (score 2):

For what it's worth, I have a Linux system and there is a command called import. This is done from a terminal window, I type in  import filename.jpg as a command, at that point the usual mouse arrow now appears as peculiar crosshairs. I then click on the web browser, which is just Firefox. The result is the creation of a jpeg called filename.jpg in the directory from which i called the import command.  Perhaps other types of machine have such a screen capture available.

=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=

[image]

=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=

Comment: The `import` command is part of the `ImageMagick` suite of image editing software. Basically it just performs a screen capture. On Windows the same effect can be achieved by hitting the `PrtScn` key and pasting the result into an image editing software.