# How can I print out an answer?

Tags: support, export

Is it possible to print out an answer somehow? What is the best way to do it if I don't have a Latex-Editor. And also assume I would have one, I could always just click at one Formula click on Right arrow. Then go to Show math as Latex Code and then only copy paste this one Formula.

Is there a smart solution for this Problem?

Comment: If you don't want to do some sort of LaTeX solution, then I think the easiest thing to do is print the page as a pdf in whatever your internet browser is.

Comment: See https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12684/what-is-the-best-way-to-print-one-answer for example

Comment: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8748/how-to-use-math-stackprinter

Comment: Maybe also that  https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/26005/

Comment: To some extent I am just repeating what has already been said in the above comments. The post [Save the answer in PDF?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/15163) mentions [StackPrinter](http://www.stackprinter.com/). The post [Save the answer in TeX/PDF - revisioned](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/25175) mentions this userscript: https://normalhuman.github.io/savetex/

Comment: Print to PDF(ctrl+p) on windows

Comment: @MartinSleziak ... I have successfully used StackPrinter.  You get better formatting that a simple screen print provided by your OS.

Comment: @Max0815 At least on mac with chrome, cmd+p is certainly a very bad suggestion...

Comment: @davidlowryduda, Firefox just prints the question, not the answers. And selecting all to print it crashes (73.0.1-1.fc31.x86_64, Fedora 31).

Comment: @vonbrand That's interesting. I just tried it out on my firefox and I agree. This is certainly undesirable. Silly firefox.